# CORS OPTIONS Request with Authorization

Tags: javascript, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm currently trying to integrate with a client's REST service and am running into the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error. I've contacted them and requested for this header to be put in the response which I am able to see if I hit the URL directly from a chrome tab (while inspecting with Fiddler). I'm also able to see the proper response headers when inspecting with the "Advanced REST Client" extension for Chrome.

Upon more testing, when calling the URL from my XMLHttpRequest, I noticed that it was not sending a "GET" request as it should but was sending an "OPTIONS" request. I've done some research on that and found this is what is known as a "pre-flight" request. I did some additional testing and when making an OPTIONS request from the REST Client chrome extension, I'm able to see the headers. However, when I inspect the response from the XMLHttpRequest in Chrome's network tab, the headers are nowhere to be found.

My first question: Is there a difference between the REST client sending an OPTIONS request and the XmlHttpRequest sending the OPTIONS request?

The next obstacle we may be facing is they require Basic Authentication to access their service. This article (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265119-Authorization-header-not-sent-on-preflight-OPTIONS-request) states that the Authorization header will not be sent for "pre-flight" requests. I just tested the XmlHttpRequest call in a Chrome Incognito window (just to make sure no previous authorization was still around) and I receive these headers within the 200 response:

```
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Connection:close
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/x-msdownload
Date:Wed, 30 Apr 2014 18:33:15 GMT
Server:[Server_Info_Here]
```

My second question is: If authorization would be preventing a successful "pre-flight" request from the XmlHttpRequest, I would not have received a 200 response, right?

Please let me know if I can provide any further details that would help explain the situation.